# Gaussianity of single-field inflation

Tags: cosmology, perturbation-theory, cosmological-inflation

I have read in multiple sources (i.e. Baumann's TASI lectures on inflation, Dodelson's *Modern Cosmology*) that single-field inflation is supposed to produce 'nearly Gaussian perturbations'. As far as I understand, this means that any relevant classical field which occurs in cosmology (say a gravitational potential $\Phi(x,t)$ or a temperature fluctuation in the CMB) has the property that when expanded in Fourier modes,
$$\Phi(x,t) = \int \frac{d^3k}{2\pi^3} \exp{(ikx)}\Phi(k,t) $$
every mode function $\Phi(k,t)$ can (at some fixed time $t$) be understood as a stochastic random variable drawn from a Gaussian distribution with certain mean and variance. This inherent stochasticity can be traced back to the quantum origin of primordial perturbations, as driven by the inflaton field.

I can't seem to find any proper reference explaining this statement. Where does this come from? How is this best understood? What would be the predictions for the mean and variance of these Gaussian distributions from theory?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does Section 3 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/9303019.pdf help?

Comment: The arguments in Weinberg's 'Cosmology' were quite satisfactory for me. Since the inflaton is nearly free in the slow-roll approximation, the two-point function is to a good approximation the only connected diagram. Once decoherence sets in (which is still quite mysterious), the field classicalizes, and Wick's theorem is still satisfied. Therefore the pdf of any linear functional of the field is Gaussian.